# How to override voice input key on Android keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, voice-recognition

I created an Activity with a button, which when clicked, starts an Intent to launch the voice input as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak Now");
startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then, I get the results and display them in a dialog so that the user can select the closest match.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        final ArrayList<String> list_voice_input = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        // I use this ArrayList to create a dialog.
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

So the Activity works as follows: Click the button, speak, and then a dialog pops up listing the closest matches and you can select one.

I have used a button-click to implement this. But Android's keyboard already has inbuilt voice input. When I use it to speak, it types out what I am saying, automatically detecting the closest match.

**What I need:**

I wish to make use of the default keyboard instead of a button, detecting when the user has chosen to speak instead of type (in a text field), and display a dialog box with the closest matches.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

**Edit:**

My question was marked as a duplicate, but I am not trying to get rid of the pop-up dialog that comes when you are recording your voice. My question is different.

When you are typing text, in the Android keyboard, there is a voice input option already inbuilt. You can use that to speak text. So, my question is, instead of automically printing out the closest match, can I show the user a list of closest matches in a dialog and ask them to select one?

Comment: You want to detect if the voice key is pressed? So you can do your thing when someone presses that button?

Comment: @Strider No, I want to know how to proceed after that. I want to get a list of closest matches instead of directly getting the spoken text printed, which is what happens by default.

Comment: @kv.333 Then you need to override that key, and make a method that does what you want. Cause I don't think you can edit it's current method.

Comment: @Strider Ah yes, that's what I needed to know. If overriding the key is the only option, I shall try that. I don't know how to access that key in code, or modify just the result list portion without spoiling the way it already works. If you know of anything that can help, please do post an answer, because that is exactly what I need.

Comment: If you want to override the key then you probably need to update the question title because your question just answers itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't change the behavior of the default keyboard like that.  There's no API to do so, to override what a single key does.  If you want this you need to interact with the speech to text API yourself, without using the keyboard.  This is built into Android (assuming the phone has a voice provider downloaded), and the API allows the voice provider to return multiple possible results.  Whether a given voice provider does or not (remember the user and OEM can install any speech to text provider they want) is something you'd have to experiment and find out.

Comment: Thanks. Before accepting your answer, I just want to clarify a point. According to your answer, the only way to get a list of results is using the code I have posted above, am I right?

Comment: Yes, assuming you want code that should work on any device with a speech to text service installed.  There's also always the option of including your own (like the sphinx library) or assuming a specific one is there (probably Google's) which may allow more options.  But that code is the most general way..